# Compare two lists of dictionaries that may or may not have a common value in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need help :P

I have this code and...

```
lista_final = [] #storethe difference beetween this two lists
lista1 = (
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'abc',
        'state': 'open',
        'scan_id': '2'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'hostname': 'bca',
        'state': 'closed',
        'scan_id': '2'
    }
)
lista2 = (
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'abc',
        'state': 'closed',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.3',
        'hostname': 'qwe',
        'state': 'open',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'hostname': 'xxx',
        'state': 'up',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
)
```

And i need to find the difference beetween then.

So i make this code

```
for l1 in lista1:  
    for l2 in lista2:
        if l1['ip'] == l2['ip']: #if ip is equal
            ip = l1['ip'] #store ip
            hostname = l1['hostname'] #default hostname
            if l1['hostname'] != l2['hostname']: #if hostnames are differente, store
                hostname = '({scan_id_l1}:{valuel1}) != ({scan_id_l2}:{valuel2})'.format(scan_id_l1=l1['scan_id'], valuel1=l1['hostname'], scan_id_l2=l2['scan_id'], valuel2=l2['hostname'])
            state = l1['state'] #default state
            if l1['state'] != l2['state']:  #if states are differente, store
                state = '({scan_id_l1}:{valuel1}) != ({scan_id_l2}:{valuel2})'.format(scan_id_l1=l1['scan_id'], valuel1=l1['state'], scan_id_l2=l2['scan_id'], valuel2=l2['state'])
            # create a temp dict
            tl = {
                'ip': ip,
                'hostname': hostname,
                'state': state
            }
            #append the temp dict to lista_final
            lista_final.append(tl)
            break #okok, go next

print(lista_final)
```

and my output is

```
[
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'abc',
        'state': '(2:open) != (3:closed)'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'hostname': '(2:bca) != (3:xxx)',
        'state': '(2:closed) != (3:up)'
    }
]
```

note that in list2 there is an ip '127.0.0.3' that does not appear in the lista_final and the result I want is this:

```
[
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'abc',
        'state': '(2:open) != (3:closed)'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'hostname': '(2:bca) != (3:xxx)',
        'state': '(2:closed) != (3:up)'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.3',
        'hostname': '(2:NOT EXIST) != (3:qwe)',
        'state': '(2:NOT EXIST) != (3:open)'
    }
]
```

Can you help me with a best solution?

Comment: `lista1` and `lista2` are not lists they are tuples.

Comment: @Muzol thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

Let's first clean up a bit your solution

```
#let's make this tuple lists
lista1 = list(lista1)
lista2 = list(lista2)

#let's sort them by ip
lista1.sort( key = lambda d : d['ip'] )
lista2.sort( key = lambda d : d['ip'] )


for dd in zip(lista1,lista2):         
        for k, v in dd[0].iteritems():
                if( v != dd[1].get(k) and k != 'scan_id' ):
                        dd[0][k] = "({}:{}) != ({}:{})".format( dd[0]['scan_id'], v, dd[1]['scan_id'], dd[1].get(k))
        dd[0].pop('scan_id')
        lista_final.append(dd[0])
```

This does pretty much the same of your code, is only doing it in place and in a more pythonic spirit. This is the output:

```
[
    {
      'hostname': 'abc',
      'ip': '127.0.0.1',
      'state': '(2:open) != (3:closed)'
     },
     {
      'hostname': '(2:bca) != (3:xxx)',
      'ip': '127.0.0.2',
      'state': '(2:closed) != (3:up)'
     }
 ]
```

You want to cover the edge case where one list is longer than the other, you can simply compare them and then repeat the operation like following

```
longer_lista = lista1 if lista1>lista2 else lista2
#iterating only through the dictionaries in the longer part of the list
for d in longer_lista[ len( zip( lista1, lista2 ) ) : ]:
        for k,v in d.iteritems():
                if( k != 'ip' and k!='scan_id' ):
                        d[k] = "({}) != ({}:{})".format( "NOT EXISTS", lista2[0]['scan_id'], v )
        lista_final.append( d )
```

This will give you an output more or less as you were expecting. Surely the code doesn't cover all the possible edge cases but is a good starting point.

```
[
    {
      'hostname': 'abc',
      'ip': '127.0.0.1',
      'state': '(2:open) != (3:closed)'
     },
     {
      'hostname': '(2:bca) != (3:xxx)',
      'ip': '127.0.0.2',
      'state': '(2:closed) != (3:up)'
     }
     {
      'hostname': '(NOT EXISTS) != (3:qwe)',
      'ip': '127.0.0.3',
      'scan_id': '3',
      'state': '(NOT EXISTS) != (3:open)'
     }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used some functions that you posted as answer here and i was able to resolve the problem!

Thanks.

## Here's the commented solution.

## The function

```
def search_diffences(list_one, list_two):
    # Store the result
    list_final = []
    
    # Sort by IP
    list_one.sort( key = lambda d : d['ip'] )
    list_two.sort( key = lambda d : d['ip'] )
    
    # Find the bigger list
    bigger_list = list_one
    smaller_list = list_two
    if len(list_two) > len(list_one):
        bigger_list = list_two
        smaller_list = list_one

    # Start the for inside for    
    for lo in bigger_list:
        found = False # Store if the result was found
        pop_i = 0 # Control what dict will be remove in the smaller_list (For code optimization)
        for lt in smaller_list:
            print("lo['ip']({0}) == lt['ip']({1}): {2}".format(lo['ip'], lt['ip'], lo['ip'] == lt['ip'])) # For debug
            if lo['ip'] == lt['ip']: # If the biggest_list as lo ['ip'] was found in smaller_list
                found = True # Set found as True
                # Store scan_id because will be used more than one time
                scan_id_lo = lo['scan_id']
                scan_id_lt = lt['scan_id']
                
                # Create a temp list for add in list_final
                ip = lo['ip']
                # Struct how i want the result
                hostname = lo['hostname']
                if lo['hostname'] != lt['hostname']:
                    hostname = '({SCAN_ID_LO}:{VALUE_LO}) != ({SCAN_ID_LT}:{VALUE_LT})'.format(
                        SCAN_ID_LO=scan_id_lo,
                        SCAN_ID_LT=scan_id_lt,
                        VALUE_LO=lo['hostname'],
                        VALUE_LT=lt['hostname']
                    )
                    
                state = lo['state']
                if lo['state'] != lt['state']:
                    state = '({SCAN_ID_LO}:{VALUE_LO}) != ({SCAN_ID_LT}:{VALUE_LT})'.format(
                        SCAN_ID_LO=scan_id_lo,
                        SCAN_ID_LT=scan_id_lt,
                        VALUE_LO=lo['state'],
                        VALUE_LT=lt['state']
                    )
                # Create the temp_list
                temp_list = {
                    'ip': ip,
                    'hostname': hostname,
                    'state': state
                }
                # Append temp_list in list_final
                list_final.append(temp_list)
                # Pop the value because so, the next for of bigger_list does not go through the first value of the smaller list again                    
                smaller_list.pop(pop_i)
                # Go to Next value of bigger_list
                break
            # pop_i++ because if the smaller list does not hit == in the first attempt, then it pops in pop_i value
            pop_i += 1
        print(found) # Debug
        if not found: # If the value of bigger list doesnt exist in smaller_list, append to list_final anyway
            scan_id_lo = lo['scan_id']
            scan_id_lt = lt['scan_id']
            
            ip = lo['ip']
            
            print("This was not found, adding to list_final", ip)
            
            hostname = '({SCAN_ID_LO}:{VALUE_LO}) != ({SCAN_ID_LT}:{VALUE_LT})'.format(
                SCAN_ID_LO=scan_id_lo,
                SCAN_ID_LT=scan_id_lt,
                VALUE_LO='NOT EXIST',
                VALUE_LT=lo['hostname']
            )
                
            state = '({SCAN_ID_LO}:{VALUE_LO}) != ({SCAN_ID_LT}:{VALUE_LT})'.format(
                SCAN_ID_LO=scan_id_lo,
                SCAN_ID_LT=scan_id_lt,
                VALUE_LO='NOT EXIST',
                VALUE_LT=lo['state']
            )
            
            temp_list = {
                'ip': ip,
                'hostname': hostname,
                'state': state
            }
            list_final.append(temp_list)
            
            # bigger_list.pop(0)

    # If smaller_list still have elements
for lt in smaller_list:
    scan_id_lt = lt['scan_id']
        
    ip = lt['ip']
    
    hostname = '({SCAN_ID_LO}:{VALUE_LO}) != ({SCAN_ID_LT}:{VALUE_LT})'.format(
        SCAN_ID_LO='NOT EXIST',
        SCAN_ID_LT=scan_id_lt,
        VALUE_LO='NOT EXIST',
        VALUE_LT=lt['hostname']
    )
        
    state = '({SCAN_ID_LO}:{VALUE_LO}) != ({SCAN_ID_LT}:{VALUE_LT})'.format(
        SCAN_ID_LO='NOT EXIST',
        SCAN_ID_LT=scan_id_lt,
        VALUE_LO='NOT EXIST',
        VALUE_LT=lt['state']
    )
    
    temp_list = {
        'ip': ip,
        'hostname': hostname,
        'state': state
    }
        
    list_final.append(temp_list) # Simple, append

return list_final
```

## The main code and the lists

```
# First List
list_one = [
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'abc',
        'state': 'open',
        'scan_id': '2'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'hostname': 'bca',
        'state': 'closed',
        'scan_id': '2'
    },
    {
        'ip': '100.0.0.4',
        'hostname': 'ddd',
        'state': 'closed',
        'scan_id': '2'
    },
    {
        'ip': '100.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'ggg',
        'state': 'up',
        'scan_id': '2'
    },
]
# Second List
list_two = [
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'abc',
        'state': 'closed',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.3',
        'hostname': 'qwe',
        'state': 'open',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'hostname': 'xxx',
        'state': 'up',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
    {
        'ip': '10.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'ddd',
        'state': 'open',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
    {
        'ip': '100.0.0.1',
        'hostname': 'ggg',
        'state': 'down',
        'scan_id': '3'
    },
]

print(search_diffences(list_one, list_two))
```

## Resulting in

```
[{
    'ip': '10.0.0.1',
    'hostname': '(3:NOT EXIST) != (2:ddd)',
    'state': '(3:NOT EXIST) != (2:open)'
}, {
    'ip': '100.0.0.1',
    'hostname': 'ggg',
    'state': '(3:down) != (2:up)'
}, {
    'ip': '127.0.0.1',
    'hostname': 'abc',
    'state': '(3:closed) != (2:open)'
}, {
    'ip': '127.0.0.2',
    'hostname': '(3:xxx) != (2:bca)',
    'state': '(3:up) != (2:closed)'
}, {
    'ip': '127.0.0.3',
    'hostname': '(3:NOT EXIST) != (2:qwe)',
    'state': '(3:NOT EXIST) != (2:open)'
}, {
    'ip': '100.0.0.4',
    'hostname': '(NOT EXIST:NOT EXIST) != (2:ddd)',
    'state': '(NOT EXIST:NOT EXIST) != (2:closed)'
}]
```